# how to get data using OnRowCommand event in c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I can not fetch data while using  `OnRowCommand` event of GridView using C# ASP.NET. I am using a linkButton inside a gridview. I am explaining my code below.

faq.aspx.cs:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //int faqID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "DoEdit":
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            int RowIndex = row.RowIndex;
            TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
            HiddenField1.Value = GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
            Button1.Text = "Update";
            break;
        }
        case  "DoDelete":
        {
            faqBL objFaqBl = new faqBL();
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            int faqID =Convert.ToInt16( GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
            objFaqBl.deleteFaqData(faqID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing `OnRowCommand` from GridView like below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="faqid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FAQ_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="question" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="answer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;" ImageUrl='<%# "/Upload/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Image")) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <!--
                    <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" id="editbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href=" " data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </a> 
                -->

                <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" CommandName="DoEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FAQ_ID") %>'>
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete" CommandName="DoDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FAQ_ID") %>'>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is the problem you're facing? what doesn't work?

Comment: @ Amit: I can not get the row data when clicked on edit link.

Comment: what is `row.RowIndex` returning?

Comment: index of that row 0,1...

Comment: I think `GridView1.Rows[index]` is what you want

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried its also not working.how to get column data of that row.

Comment: do you get null with `GridView1.Rows[index]`?

Comment: i am getting `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow` from `GridView1.Rows[index]`.

Comment: you can simply access `Cells` property then.

Comment: i can not acess cells value.

Comment: what is wrong there?